# How to obtain array or list from a dataframe (in which python read as a str format type)?

Tags: python, arrays, pandas, dataframe

I have a data frame that, where python read the columns in each row a str type. But its actually a list or an array. How I want to obtain my array from the str format?

I already try to split function, but its give weird output.

#### I cant post images due to low reputation

Lets say this is my dataframe (NOT ACTUAL DATA)

[image]

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'Weight':[str([45, 88, 56]), str([15, 71, 62])], 
                   'Name':[str(['Sam', 'Andrea', 'Alex']), str(['Robin', 'Kia', 'Lina'])], 
                   'Age':[str([14, 25, 55]), str([8, 21, 30])]})
```

If we check the format of first row & first columns is a str format

```
type(df['Weight'][0])
>> str
```

If we use split function, I obtain,

```
pd.DataFrame(np.column_stack((df['Weight'][0].split(), df['Age'][0].split())))
>> array([['[45,', '[14,'],
       ['88,', '25,'],
       ['56]', '55]']], dtype='<U4')
```

[image]

### My expected output is to able to gain the array.

[image]

```
array([45, 88, 56], dtype=int64)
```

i'm still new in python. Its there any fastest function that already built in python, rather than I need to replace the `[ , ]` as null.

Comment: check `ast.literal_eval()`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

maybe you can try this way, by using `ast module`, make the string into a list & set the list into np.array.

```
import ast
df = pd.DataFrame({'Weight':[str([45, 88, 56]), str([15, 71, 62])], 
                   'Name':[str(['Sam', 'Andrea', 'Alex']), str(['Robin', 'Kia', 'Lina'])], 
                   'Age':[str([14, 25, 55]), str([8, 21, 30])]}) 

a = np.array(ast.literal_eval(df['Weight'][0]))
b = np.array(ast.literal_eval(df['Age'][0]))
pd.DataFrame(np.column_stack((a, b)))
```

Comment: doesn't aware with the function `ast.literal_eval()` . thanks

Answer (score 1):

You could use several splits to get what you want. You use two splits to get rid of the brackets, and then a last split to extract the values.

It could look soomething like that :

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'Weight':[str([45, 88, 56]), str([15, 71, 62])], 
                   'Name':[str(['Sam', 'Andrea', 'Alex']), str(['Robin', 'Kia', 'Lina'])], 
                   'Age':[str([14, 25, 55]), str([8, 21, 30])]}) 



df['Weight'] = [x.split('[')[1].split(']')[0].split(',') for x in df['Weight']]
df['Name'] = [x.split('[')[1].split(']')[0].split(',') for x in df['Name']]
df['Age'] = [x.split('[')[1].split(']')[0].split(',') for x in df['Age']]

In [1] : type(df['Weight'][0])
Out[1] : list
```

And if you want a numpy array instead of a list, you can change your list comprehension to :

```
df['Weight'] = [np.array(x.split('[')[1].split(']')[0].split(',')) for x in df['Weight']]
df['Name'] = [np.array(x.split('[')[1].split(']')[0].split(',')) for x in df['Name']]
df['Age'] = [np.array(x.split('[')[1].split(']')[0].split(',')) for x in df['Age']]

In [1] : type(df['Weight'][0])
Out[1] : numpy.ndarray
```